# pass object by value between threads

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to pass objects **by value** between threads with a queue.

Because there are multiple different objects, I made an abstract class.

```
class message
{
public :
      virtual ~message(){};
};
```

then I have a subclass for each different type of message

```
class a_specific_message : public message
{
...
};
```

I read [this tutorial](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html) for implementing the queue and I call it the following way:

```
concurrent_queue<message> queue;
a_specific_message m{1, 2, 3};
queue.push(m);
```

My problem is that I need to override the `operator=` so the queue can clone the message

```
popped_value=the_queue.front();
```

I tried to add a virtual operator but it doesn't get called in the subclass.

I don't know how I could achieve something like this without passing object by reference.

Comment: `concurrent_queue<message>` holds **objects** of type `message`. When you push an object of a derived type into the queue, the object gets sliced and all that's stored is the `message` part of it. There's no way to get the original object back once that's happened. You need a queue that holds references or pointers.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was scared that this would happen. How do I make sure that the other thread delete the object when it's done?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `shared_ptr` (which is thread safe)

Comment: @Marc create virtual destructor

Comment: @W.F. Still gets sliced. Needs a pointer or reference.

Comment: @Marc In my opinion, virtual functions and inheritance is not the answer. You should have different queue for different types of messages, and only access the queue you need for the message types you need.

Comment: @Donnie Might want to elborate that a little bit.  Construction and destruction is thread safe, access is not.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot You can invite extra synchronization problems with multiple queues. I usually waste space here and make one generic intertask message and switch interpretations on an enum message type. Mind you I'm also coming in from C and this may be a really stupid thing to do in C++.

Comment: @Donnie I didn't want to use pointers because devs will have to remember to delete it in another thread. It could be easy to forget and have a memory leak. Shared_ptr won't fix that

Comment: @Marc `std::shared_ptr` is a ref counting smart pointer, and take care of deleting the pointer when the count goes down to `0`. You don't need to manually delete it and it doesn't leak memory.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Wow this is fantastic! It's amazing. Thank you

Comment: @Marc you should take a look at my answer, it shows how to do it with unique pointers, which are much more lightweight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, polymorphism is not what you really want. An interface with nothing but a destructor and dynamic downcast usually means that you are using the wrong tool.

---

However, if polymorphism is what you want, let me propose `std::unique_ptr`. You can have here you queue of pointers declared like that: `concurrent_queue<std::unique_ptr<message>>`

As you told in the comments:

> I didn't want to use pointers because devs will have to remember to delete it in another thread. It could be easy to forget and have a memory leak.

Then I think `std::unqiue_ptr` is the right thing for you.

If I translate your code, it would look like that:

```
concurrent_queue<std::unique_ptr<message>> queue;
auto m = std::make_unique<a_specific_message>(1, 2, 3);

queue.push(std::move(m));
```

Or simply:

```
concurrent_queue<std::unique_ptr<message>> queue;

queue.push(std::make_unique<a_specific_message>(1, 2, 3));
// Or
queue.push(new a_specific_message{1, 2, 3});
```

Then, to pop values:

```
auto popped_value = std::move(the_queue.front());
```

Then everything is deleted automatically, without having to remember to delete any pointer. `std::unique_ptr` has been created for that purpose.

To avoid the explicit move in your code, you could have something like `pop_value` in your queue, implemented like that:

```
T pop_value() {
    auto value = std::move(the_queue.front());

    the_queue.pop();

    // use nrvo
    return value;
}
```

So now, in your threads, you can safely do that:

```
{
    auto some_message = queue.pop_value();

    // stuff

} // some_message deleted here.
```

Comment: Is make_unique c++14? I get an error saying it's not a member of std and I'm using c++11

Comment: Yes, `std::make_unique` is part of C++14. You can however replace `std::make_unique` with a plain old `new`

Comment: @Marc see my edit. I added an example with new, which is compatible with `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Thank you but are you sure this would work? You push a a_specific_message instead of a unique_ptr. I get an error for that

Comment: I did this instead : std::unique_ptr<a_specific_message>(new a_specific_message(1,2,3));

Answer (score 2):

As @PeteBecker writes in the comments, `concurrent_queue<message>` holds `message`'s by value. When a derived object instance is pushed into the queue it makes a copy of `message` part only. Slicing occurs.

One way to make the queue hold objects of multiple types without resorting to pointers is to use a discriminated union, e.g. [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/variant.html):

```
using message = boost::variant<specific_message_a, specific_message_b>;
```

No common base class for messages is required here.

The downside of this approach is that `sizeof(message)` is `sizeof` of the largest type in that `boost::variant<>` template argument list.